# How find Number of integer solutions $x_{1}+x_{2}+\cdots+x_{n}=m$

Tags: combinatorics

**Question:**

**let $m$ and $n$ be positive integers,The number of positive integer solutions to the equation**

> $$x_{1}+x_{2}+\cdots+x_{n}=m,m\ge n,x_{i}\ge 1,1\le x_{1}\le x_{2}\le\cdots\le x_{n},(i=1,2,\cdots,n)$$
>   is $f(m,n)$,How find this close form $f(m,n)?$

I know this therom:

> Let $n$ and $m$ be positive integers,The number of positive integer solution to the equation
>   $$x_{1}+x_{2}+\cdots+x_{m}=n(n\ge m)$$ is
>   $$N=\binom{n-1}{m-1}$$

But for my problem,I can't prove it.Thank you

**BY the way**

In 2010 China math competition,there is this problem

> find the total  number of sets of positive integer $(x,y,z)$,where $x,y$ and $z$ are positive integers, with  $x\le y\le z$
>   and such that
>   $$x+y+z=2010$$
>
> this answer is $$336675$$

can see this PDF：(problem 8) http://wenku.baidu.com/view/9a59934ee518964bcf847cba.html

**and I also Find this same problem is Sinapore Mathematical Olympiad (SMO)2012 Problem 4:**

> find the total  number of sets of positive integer $(x,y,z)$,where $x,y$ and $z$ are positive integers, with  $x\le y\le z$
>   and such that
>   $$x+y+z=203$$

**This follow is office Solution(Maybe is wrong)**.

First note that there are $\binom{202}{2}=\dfrac{202(201)}{2}=20301$ positive integers sets$(x,y,z)$ which satisfy the given equation.These solution sets include those where two of the three values are equal.if $x=y$ then $2x+z=203$,By enumeerating,$z=1,3,5,\cdots,201$.There are thus $101$ solutions of the form $(x,x,z)$, similarly,there are $101$ solutions of the form $(x,y,x)$ and $(x,y,y)$,since $x<y<z$,the required answer is
$$\dfrac{1}{3!}\left(\binom{202}{2}-3(101)\right)=\dfrac{20301-303}{6}=3333$$

Comment: $336675$ is the number of partitions of $2010$ into $3$ positive terms and is $\dfrac{2010^2}{12}$ though in other cases you may need to round

Comment: The answer to your Singapore Mathematical Olympiad question should be $3434$

Comment: I agree with you,it seem this office answer is wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suppose we want to count the number of non-decreasing sequences of $n$ non-negative integers which sum to $m$. That is, $a_{k+1}\ge a_k$ and
$$
\sum_{k=1}^na_k=m\tag{1}
$$
Note that if we set $a_0=0$, then
$$
\begin{align}
m
&=\sum_{k=1}^na_k\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^k(a_j-a_{j-1})\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{k=j}^n(a_j-a_{j-1})\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^n(n-j+1)(a_j-a_{j-1})\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
The following diagram illustrates $(2)$ for $n=4$:

$\hspace{4.5cm}$[image]

Consider the product
$$
\overbrace{(1+x^n+x^{2n}+\dots)}^{\large x^{(a_1-a_0)n}}
\overbrace{(1+x^{n-1}+x^{2(n-1)}+\dots)}^{\large x^{(a_2-a_1)(n-1)}}
\dots\overbrace{(1+x+x^2+\dots)}^{\large x^{a_n-a_{n-1}}}\tag{3}
$$
In the first factor, we choose $x^{(a_1-a_0)n}$. In the second factor, we choose $x^{(a_2-a_1)(n-1)}$. In the $k^\text{th}$ factor, we choose $x^{(a_k-a_{k-1})(n-k+1)}$. In the product, the coefficient of $x^m$ is the number of ways to make the sum in $(2)$.

The product in $(3)$ can be rewritten as
$$
\prod_{k=1}^n\frac1{1-x^k}\tag{4}
$$
The coefficient of $x^m$ in $(4)$ is the number of non-decreasing sequences of $n$ non-negative integers which sum to $m$.

---

The number of non-decreasing sequences of $n$ positive integers that sum to $m$ is the number of non-decreasing sequences of $n$ non-negative integers that sum to $m-n$. Just add $1$ to each element of the latter to get the former.

The number of increasing sequences of $n$ positive integers that sum to $m$ is the number of non-decreasing sequences of $n$ non-negative integers that sum to $m-n(n+1)/2$. Just add $k$ to the $k^\text{th}$ element of the latter to get the former.

The number of increasing sequences of $n$ non-negative integers that sum to $m$ is the number of non-decreasing sequences of $n$ non-negative integers that sum to $m-n(n-1)/2$. Just add $k-1$ to the $k^\text{th}$ element of the latter to get the former.

---

The number of non-decreasing sequences of $3$ positive integers that sum to $2010$ is the coefficient of $x^{2007}$ in
$$
\prod_{k=1}^3\frac1{1-x^k}\tag{5}
$$
which is $336675$. This matches the answer you give.

The number of increasing sequences of $3$ positive integers that sum to $203$ is the coefficient of $x^{197}$ in $(5)$, which is $3333$. This matches the official solution. However, the question asks for the number of *non-decreasing* sequences of $3$ positive integers that sum to $203$, which is the coefficient of $x^{200}$ in $(5)$, $3434$.

---

**Closed Form for $(5)$**

Since $(5)$ is the inverse of
$$
(1-x)(1-x^2)(1-x^3)=1-x-x^2+x^4+x^5-x^6\tag{6}
$$
the coefficients of $(5)$ are determined by
$$
a_n=a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}-a_{n-4}-a_{n-5}+a_{n-6}\\
(a_0,a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5,\dots)=(1,1,2,3,4,5,\dots)\tag{7}
$$
Since the roots of $(6)$ are $\left\{1,1,1,-1,e^{2\pi i/3},e^{-2\pi i/3}\right\}$, the solution of $(7)$ looks like
$$
a_n=c_0+c_1n+c_2n^2+c_3(-1)^n+c_4\cos(2\pi n/3)+c_5\sin(2\pi n/3)\tag{8}
$$
Using the initial values from $(7)$, we can compute the coefficients in $(8)$:
$$
a_n=\frac1{72}\left(47+36n+6n^2+9(-1)^n+16\cos(2\pi n/3)\right)\tag{9}
$$
Note that $9(-1)^n+16\cos(2\pi n/3)$ repeats mod $6$: $(25,-17,1,7,1,-17)$. Putting this together with $(9)$ yields
$$
a_n=\left\lfloor\frac{12+6n+n^2}{12}\right\rfloor\tag{10}
$$
Using $(10)$, we get $a_{2007}=336675$, $a_{197}=3333$, and $a_{200}=3434$, just as above.

Comment: Oh,Thank you very much.It's very nice +1

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for the partition of $m$ in $n$ positive parts.

You can solve this using a generating function, taking the coefficient of $x^m$ in the expansion of $$\frac{x^n}{\displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^{n} (1-x^i)}$$ or by recursion, which is used in my Java applet at http://www.se16.info/js/partitions.htm : so if you ask for partitions of $2010$ into exactly $3$ parts you get a result of $336675$; partitions of $203$ into exactly $3$ parts gives $3434$.

Looking at what you call the "office solution", there are indeed $20301$ compositions of $203$ into $3$ positive parts and $3 \times 101$ of these have two parts the same.  So there are $\frac{20301-3\times 101}{3!} = 3333$ partitions of $203$ into $3$ distinct positive parts.  But there are also $101$ partitions of $203$ into $3$ positive parts where two (but not three) are identical, giving the correct answer of $3333+101=3434$.

Comment: Thank you,can we  find this $f(m,n)$ Gradual estimate expression?

Comment: becasuse I know this $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}f(n)x^n=\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{1-x^k}$$,then we have $$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\dfrac{\ln{f(n)}}{\sqrt{n}}=\dfrac{\sqrt{6}}{3}\pi$$,so I guess $f(m,n)$ maybe have same as nice results?Thank you

Comment: For $m$ much bigger than $n$, I suspect you have something like the number of partitions of $m$ in $n$ positive parts is of the order of $\dfrac{m^{n-1}}{n! (n-1)!}$

Comment: I believe that the generating function should be $$\frac{x^n}{\displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^{n} (1\color{#C00000}{-}x^i)}$$ otherwise, the coefficient of $x^{203}$ would be $34$ and the coefficient of $x^{2010}$ would be $-335$.

Comment: @robjohn - Thank you - I will edit the $+$ to a $-$.

Answer (score 3):

The theorem gives you the number of solutions of $x_{1} + \cdots + x_{n} = m$ that are permutations dependent ; this is called the [stars & bars theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29). For example, $(1;2;1;2)$ and $(1;1;2;2)$ are 2 distinct solutions if $n=4$ and $m=6$.

However here you would only consider increasing sequences as solutions. These are called **integer partitions**. More precisely you want to find the number $f(m,n)$ of partitions of $m$ in $n$ parts $\geq 1$. Unfortunately, as far as I know, there is no (simple) closed form of $f(m,n)$. Its generating function, on the other hand, has a simple expression
$$\sum_{m,n=1}^{\infty} f(m,n) x^{n}q^{m} = \prod_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1-xq^{m}}$$

To find $f(m,n)$, one can then compute the term in front of $x^{n}q^{m}$ in the RHS. One can then use Taylor expansion to find it numerically.

### Some closed forms of $f(m,n)$

The [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29) about integer partitions happens to have closed forms of $f(m,n)$ for the first few values of $n$

- **$n=1$** : Obviously for all $m$, $f(m,1) =1$
- **$n=2$** :
  $$f(m,2)=\left\lfloor \frac{m}{2} \right\rfloor$$
- **$n\leq 3$** : According to Hardy's paper [Some Famous Problems of the Theory of Numbers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1434433137), $\displaystyle f(m,n\leq 3) = \sum_{n=1}^{3}f(m,n)$ is the nearest integer to
  $$\frac{(m+3)^2}{12}$$

Comment: Thank you,can we  find this $f(m,n)$ Gradual estimate expression?

Comment: becasuse I know this $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}f(n)x^n=\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{1-x^k}$$,then we have $$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\dfrac{\ln{f(n)}}{\sqrt{n}}=\dfrac{\sqrt{6}}{3}\pi$$,so I guess $f(m,n)$ maybe have same as nice results?Thank you

Comment: @chinamath I don't know what you exactly mean by gradual estimate, but you can use Taylor expansion to derive $f(m,n)$ - at least for the first few values of $m$ and $n$. However, even if you can find the asymptotic behaviour of $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(m,n)$$ The asymptotic behaviour of $f(m,n)$ itself doesn't really make sense (except if you fix $n$, and in that case I don't know if it has the same behaviour sorry).

Comment: @Tristan: in my answer, I derive the exact formula for $f(m,3)=\left\lfloor\frac{12+6m+m^2}{12}\right\rfloor$.